# función windows scroll que se ejecute solo en index o pagina de inicio

Tags: scroll

Estimados tengo una función   windows scroll, la cual trabaja bien pero esta en un archivo js externo, y este js es único para todo el sitio, esta función solo se ejecuta o me sirve solo en el index,  pero se comparte con las demas paginas del sitio, el tema es que esta función busca ejecutase en dichas paginas internas y me da un menaje de error en consola sobre todo la propiedad top me indica undefined.

como puedo decir que la función scroll solo se ejecute en  la pagina de inicio o index y no en las paginas interiores. vuelvo a mencionar comparten el mismo archivo js.

Gracias.

dejo el js que utilizo.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                var objectSelect = $(".content");
                var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
                if (scroll > objectPosition) {
                    $(".bar1").css("background", '#000000');
                } else {
                    $(".bar1").css("background", '#ffffff');
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Creo que lo correcto es que insertes ese código en una función de tu archivo .js compartido y mandes a llamar esa función sólo en el index dentro de un tag `<script>`

```
function indexScroll(){
    $(window).scroll(function() {
                var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
                var objectSelect = $(".content");
                var objectPosition = objectSelect.offset().top;
                if (scroll > objectPosition) {
                    $(".bar1").css("background", '#000000');
                } else {
                    $(".bar1").css("background", '#ffffff');
                }
            });
}
```

y en tu archivo de index:

```
$(document.ready(function(){
      indexScroll();
}
```

Comment: Hola Gracias por responder, si eso funcionaria, pero no puedo o no me permiten incluir js embebido en los archivos HTML. Otra solución seria incluir otro js, solo para el index, pero tampoco me lo permiten. se necesita solo del único js que las funciones scroll solo afecten o se ejecuten en el index. gracias